# Can I make Typescript ignore proptype checking for JS React components?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx, react-proptypes, tsx

I'm working on a large JS component library (50+ components) and trying to introduce TS support so that components can be written in Typescript OR Javascript, and imported from either TS or JS projects. Because of the large number of components, I'm not rewriting every component - just a single component to start with.

The compilation and export of components works fine for TSX and simple JSX components, but for even slightly more complex JSX, it breaks down.

Here's a simple JSX component that I'm not ready to convert to TSX yet:

```
import { string } from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';

export default function MyComponent(props) {
  const { className, ...otherProps } = props;
  const fullClassName = [className, 'my-component-class'].join(' ');
  return <div className={fullClassName} {...otherProps} />;
}

MyComponent.propTypes = {
  className: string,
};
```

...and the corresponding generated `.d.ts` file:

```
declare function MyComponent(props: any): JSX.Element;
declare namespace MyComponent {
    namespace propTypes {
        export { string as className };
    }
}
export default MyComponent;
import { string } from "prop-types";
```

In theory, now, I should be able to import and use this in a TS project:

```
import { MyComponent } from 'some-common-lib';

export default function SomeWidget() {
   return (
     <MyComponent>
        <div>some text</div>
        <div>some other text</div>
     </MyComponent>
   );
}
```

...but this generates a type error, because I'm passing an implicit `children` prop which isn't recognised:

```
Type '{ children: Element[] }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & InferPropsInner<Pick<typeof propTypes, never>> & Partial<InferPropsInner<Pick<typeof propTypes, "className">>>'.
   Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & InferPropsInner<Pick<typeof propTypes, never>> & Partial<InferPropsInner<Pick<typeof propTypes, "className">>>'.
```

My assumption is that this long constructed type is being used internally by React as part of `React.createElement()`, but the documentation for Typescript doesn't cover the process.

While I could solve this problem by rewriting every single component in the library to Typescript, we're not ready to do that yet as it's too much of a commitment/risk (and too much testing to go through for each application that uses the components).

I had the idea of writing a script that deletes type definition files for all JS-only components, and only leaves them in place for TS components (and `index.js` files that export them). This seems like an inelegant kludge but may be my only option.

My hope was that there is a way to either:

- configure the output of `tsc` so that proptypes for JS components are more permissive (the documentation is not clear on this!) OR
- configure the output of `tsc` so that it doesn't produce type declarations for JS component files OR
- configure the compilation of consuming applications so that it ignores inferred prop types and instead just treats the components as plain functions that allow any props (as it would if we were importing a plain JS library). Again, TS documentation doesn't acknowledge this behaviour, so I have no idea how this would work.

I can't see a way to accomplish any of these - are they possible?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the bug in a clean React environment, code executes perfectly.
Can you try putting the MyComponent children prop inside the div tags? `return <div className={fullClassName} {...otherProps}>{props.children}</div>;`

Answer (score 1):

Since [React 18](https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18.html) and [the corresponding version of `@types/react`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/56210), you need to explicitly specify the `children` prop.

```
import { string, element } from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';

export default function MyComponent(props) {
  const { className, ...otherProps } = props;
  const fullClassName = [className, 'my-component-class'].join(' ');
  return <div className={fullClassName} {...otherProps} />;
}

MyComponent.propTypes = {
  className: string,
  children: element,
};
```

I'm not used to using `prop-types` so you might need to tweak this code.

If you were only targeting Typescript, you could rewrite your code this way:

```
import React from 'react';

interface MyComponentProps {
  className: string;
  children?: ReactNode;
}

export default function MyComponent({ className, ...otherProps }: MyComponentProps) {
  const fullClassName = [className, 'my-component-class'].join(' ');
  return <div className={fullClassName} {...otherProps} />;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Valentin! Is this change documented anywhere? I find it very hard to find API info on TS React.

Comment: It was documented in [this pull request](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/56210) but I agree it's not easily discoverable. Facebook uses [flow](https://flow.org/) rather than Typescript, so that's a reason why important Typescript types changes weren't documented in [React 18 release notes](https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18.html).